# How to make scrimColor full screen in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

please help, I want to make scrimColor full screen, can anyone solve this ?

[image: please look this image]

Here is my code, I want scrimColor whole screen , but not taking full screen, can anyone solve this ?
I am using kotlin jetpack compose, I am tried to done this, but fails,
I AM using modalBottomSheet material3, very easy but i have tried.
please help me

```
`@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun BottomExample() {
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Scaffold(

        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text("My App") },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* Handle navigation icon click */ }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "Menu")
                    }
                }
            )
        },

        floatingActionButton = {
            ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                text = { Text("Show bottom sheet") },
                icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "") },
                onClick = {
                    showBottomSheet = true
                }
            )
        }
    ) { contentPadding ->

        Box(
            Modifier
                .padding(paddingValues = contentPadding)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            if (showBottomSheet) {
                ModalBottomSheet(
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        showBottomSheet = false
                    },
                    sheetState = sheetState,

                    scrimColor = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .navigationBarsPadding()
                        .systemBarsPadding()
                        .statusBarsPadding(),
                ) {
                    // Sheet content
                    Box(
                        Modifier

                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .navigationBarsPadding()
                            .captionBarPadding()
                            .imePadding()
                            .statusBarsPadding(),
                    ) {
                        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                            Button(onClick = {
                                scope.launch { sheetState.hide() }.invokeOnCompletion {
                                    if (!sheetState.isVisible) {
                                        showBottomSheet = false
                                    }
                                }
                            }) {
                                Text("Hide bottom sheet")
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}`
```

Comment: Modal Bottom Sheet should be outside Scaffold for the scrim to be over the Top App Bar. But I am also looking for a solution to make the scrim above status bar as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to get scrim on the status bar as well.

[image]

Steps,

1. As commented in the question, the first step would be to make the `ModalBottomSheetLayout` the parent of the `Scaffold`.
2. Enabled Edge to Edge

You can do this by adding this line to the activity.

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

3. Ensure the status bar color is transparent.

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
```

I have tested in API 33.
Kindly check if it also works for lower API and add comments if there are any issues.